# A number with leading zero and optional decimal (sql)

Tags: mysql, types, sqldatatypes

I am designing something similar to reading a book online. 
As we all know, there are chapters in mostly every book. every chapter has a number: 01, 02 and so on.
right now, I have some chapters that have a decimal number like : 01.5, 02.5 and so on.
My MySQL data type now is "smallint" with only 4 characters are allowed, with the attribute "unsigned zerofill".
so right now, If I typed something like : "1" 
it is going to store it as : 0001
If the number have decimal or anything other than numbers it won't store it. 
which leads to my question, is there anyway I can make it support decimal numbers. Plus, I do not want it to show decimal if the decimal is 0.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you manage if some books have chapters like 1.5.1 or 1.4.5.3 etc. In these cases none of the numeric datatype would be helpful as they allow only single dot. My suggestion is to use varchar for your column

Comment: I was thinking about it. but that will let the user who adds the book to use any character(letter-numbers-others) in the chapter number, which I do not want! Plus, I want it to have zero-leading. 

In addition to all of this, this will let the user add a chapter called 01 and a chapter called 1 and a chapter called 0001 etc.

Comment: You are supposed to store data in database, not data + formatting.

Comment: @shnisaka you have to validate the values in your server-side code e.g. php, asp whatever you use. If the values contains non-numeric characters then you show an error message like invalid chapter number. For your leading zeros issue this is also done on server-side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not store number that way. What you should do is to store it as *decimal* and format it upon retrieving from database.

For example if this is the schema of a table,

```
CREATE TABLE amount (value decimal(5,2));
```

In PHP number can be formatted like,

```
$res = mysql_query("select * from amount");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    printf ("%07.2f", $row['value']);
}
```

This `printf` function format will print `2.9` as `0002.90`

Comment: please explain more, how do you do it in my case? give me some examples if possible

Comment: Format the data on your front end language. What is your Front end language?

Comment: quick question, what if I wanted to do the opposite?

Comment: from 0002.90 to 2.9. will the servers now it be default? or is there a code that removes the zeros?

Comment: another question, If I have a number that looks like this : 233.0 will it output  0233? or 0233.0? how can I make it out put 0233 if It did not was outputting 0233.0?

Comment: @shnisaka It depends on the language you are using at the front end. You haven't still told me this.

Comment: If I store it with 4 numbers plus 1 decimal (0001.0) I want something that I can use in php to not show the the decimal if it was 0 
so instead of showing it 0001.0 I want it to be 0001
and if has a decimal like : 0001.9 I do not want to edit it